# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sift'

Tags: linux

I want to use sift() in python &openCV
here is my environment:
python:2.7.6
os:ubuntu 14.04
opencv:2.4.9

After several hours hard-work, now i seem to successfully install opencv,because i can do as below:
    import cv2
    print cv2.**version**   ---- 2.4.9

now my problem is that when i want to call cv2.sift(),it says AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sift'

If i download opencv_contrib from github and use cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/modules , the compiling will fail , it says:
    **Module opencv_xfeatures2d disabled because opencv_shape dependency can't be resolved!**

someone else even says the opencv_contrib can only work with opencv3

then how can i solve this problem? I need your help~

Comment: Do you mean `cv2.SIFT()`?

Comment: oh thank u ,i forget python in windows also case sensitive,now I find that this fonction is OK both in my win and linux!

Comment: no prob, you're welcome